# Current page ID on WooCommerce page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a WooCommerce plugin for WordPress. Now in a file page.php I am trying to get the current opened page id via `$post->ID` and `the_id()` but all I am getting is the product ID and not the current page ID. Probably because WooCommerce overwrites the loop ?

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you trying to get it inside a loop or something? Tried to get it at the top of the page?

Comment: Jimmie, i've tried to get it at the top of the page at woocommerce.php file inside my root template. Still the same results.

Comment: can you please share code...? so that we can help you better

Answer (score 12):

It might be too late, but i was trying to get the same result as you and this below worked pretty well for me:

```
<?php 
  if(is_shop()){
    $page_id = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');
  }else{
    $page_id = $post->ID;
  }
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The best answer so far and it helped me a lot... thanks! Calling `get_post_meta($post->ID 'custom_field', true);` to retrieve a custom field's data previously set up with CMB2 plugin for pages was not working within my WooCommerce templates. So the above allowed me do anything that involves passing a WooCommerce specific page ID. Other "WC" conditional tags might be useful to improve the above code snippet.  http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Succinct is sexy: 
`$post_id = is_shop() ? wc_get_page_id('shop') : get_the_ID();`

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to get the particular page id. Try with this.

```
if ( wc_get_page_id( 'name of page' ) != get_the_ID()):
```

This worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

`global $post;$post->ID;` or `global $wp_query;$wp_query->post->ID;` don't work with woocommerce. You can get all the id's of woocommerce page [here](https://gist.github.com/Bradley-D/7287723)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, inspired by **woocommerce_product_archive_description**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'custom_name', 11, 2); 

function custom_name() {
  if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && 0 === absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ) :

    global $post;
    $shop_page = get_post( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );

    if ( $shop_page ) {
      $post = $shop_page;
    }
    // your code here

  endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$woo_pages_id = array(
    //get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ), 
    get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ), 
    get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ), 
    //get_option( 'woocommerce_pay_page_id' ), 
    //get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ), 
    get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ),
    //get_option( 'woocommerce_edit_address_page_id' ), 
    //get_option( 'woocommerce_view_order_page_id' ), 
    get_option( 'woocommerce_terms_page_id' )
);

$current_page_id = get_the_ID();

if ( in_array($current_page_id, $woo_pages_id) ) : 
    get_template_part('content/woo', 'pages');
else :
    get_template_part('content', 'page');
endif;
```

I'm using this for my page.php file.

Answer (score -1):

put this line above your code or at starting of script.

```
global $post;
```

now you can use `$post->ID;`

thanks

Comment: I tried that Krunal, but it's returning the ID of the first post in the loop (product) and not the current page ID.

Comment: @krunal how can I access the current product id in a custom plugin

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem found a solution [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-customising-the-shop-base-page#post-3623488)
The code I used on my shop page was:

```
<?php echo woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'); ?>
```

Basically replace the `shop` value with whatever woocommerce page you are trying to get.

More documentation on the function and some other helpful functions can be found [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/useful-functions/)